# length of varchar store in mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, varchar

> Sorry, English isn't my first language... :(

I want to learn the actual length of varchar how to store in mysql .ibd file. So I deside to make a test like this:

```
CREATE TABLE record_format_demo (
         c1 VARCHAR(10),
        c2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
         c3 CHAR(10),
         c4 VARCHAR(10)
     ) CHARSET=ascii ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO record_format_demo(c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES('aaaa', 'bbb', 'cc', 'd');

SELECT * FROM record_format_demo;
+------+-----+------+------+
| c1   | c2  | c3   | c4   |
+------+-----+------+------+
| aaaa | bbb | cc   | d    |
+------+-----+------+------+
```

and I open ibd file by ultraEdit, the varchar length in hex look like this:
[image]

- HEX 01 is c4's length, decimal is 1
- HEX 03 is c2's length, decimal is 3
- HEX 04 is c1's length , decimal is 4

but these column's value is too short, just need one byte can count, so I do another test like this :

```
CREATE TABLE record_format_demo2 (
         c1 VARCHAR(10),
        c2 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
         c3 CHAR(10),
         c4 VARCHAR(357)
     ) CHARSET=ascii ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
         
         
INSERT INTO record_format_demo2(c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES('aaaa', REPEAT('a',127), 'cc', REPEAT('a', 356));
```

and it's ibd file like this :

[image]

- HEX 04 is c1's length ,because 'aaaa' only have 4 char
- HEX 7F is c2's length, decimal is 127, because c2 = REPEAT('a',127)

But hex of C4's length is `64 81` ，it's decimal is `25729` . More than `356`. I try to plus two HEX ,But `64 + 81 = E5` which decimal is 229, not equal `356`.

It make me confuse , So I want to know why hex of c4 show like this., and how can I figure out `356`

Comment: Including your next byte gets you 356: hex `64 + 81 + 7F` = decimal `356`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But 7F is the length of C2，because I change `REPEAT('a',127)` to `REPEAT('a',124)`, the `7F` will change too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this:

- x81 is 01 with the high bit on
- The high bit says "this number is continued"
- The continuation is x64
- Putting the pieces together gives x0164 = decimal 356

Have you found where/how the NULL flags show up?

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right! I try to change `c2` to `REPEAT('a', 128)`, and I got hex `80 80`.

with you explanation， `80` = `1000 0000` says `this number is continued`, so full binary is `8000` = `10000000 00000000` = decimal 128.

Comment: But I want to know why you use `Little-Endian` to transform the hex to decimal?

Comment: @HashMap - because it seemed to work.  The endian-ness of the internal workings of MySQL is deliberately consistent across all hardware implementations -- so that the disk files can be moved without change.  I don't know why they picked little-endian two decades ago; but it does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I Don't know if it's a bit of a waste of time to research this as a Javaer, but human curiosity drives me and makes me want to understand the whole process.

Comment: @HashMap - I've been curious, but not enough to look at the code.  What is a "Javaer"?

Comment: Aha, 'Javaer' is chinese english, Sorry :) .
I mean a programmer working in java development

Comment: @HashMap - Now that you tell me, it makes sense (Java + er).  There are a lot of aspects of Computer Science.  It's good to reach off in different directions.  Java mostly hides bits and encodings from programmers.  Encodings in bits and bytes is another dimension to learning Computer Science.